# Filtering tags from Cassandra 3.x

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We have an activity metrics page where users can select a date period and see other user's aggregated activity (by action) and optionally filter everything by 4 or 5 fields. Actions happen sequentially, but one of the fields is `Tags` and the user may change old action's tags anytime. The data is in a Cassandra 3.7 with the partition key being `(company_id, action_year, action_week)`. For each week we have about 70k actions (there are 20 columns with `long` or `int` data for each action, each action with the partition key plus `action_timestamp` and `action_key` as row key).

```
PRIMARY KEY ((company_id, action_year, action_week), action_date, action_key)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (action_date ASC, action_key ASC)
```

With a first version we are querying the full actions for a period and doing all the aggregations and filtering in memory. When the user selects a couple of weeks, the whole request takes like 10 or 15 secs. And we are expecting to scale to thousands of users requesting these analytics that should work as near real time analytics.

We thought of moving the filtering to C* using "allow filtering", but the WHERE clause seems very limited. And we are also worried about the frequent updates for the labels.

What's the right way of using C* here?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Cassandra 3.7 you should consider using SASI. It is a newer feature allowing more powerful secondary indexes in Cassandra. Documentation is available [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndexConcept.html).

But as this is a new feature make sure you fully test it for your usecase and really dig into the operations of the index to make sure your usecase fits well.

Another good article to start with is [this preview one](http://rustyrazorblade.com/2016/02/cassandra-secondary-index-preview-1/).

Comment: "Currently, SASI does not support collections". I need multiple tags, so collections is a must

Comment: Are you sure you want to store tags as a collection? It may make more sense to just keep them as text inside C*. If you need to semantics of collections then you seem to be kinda stuck.

Comment: Yes, I could keep them as text and use LIKE. But then again I can't use OR in a WHERE clause, right?